# Date : setTimeZone not detected

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a date in millis to a date and get the time.

I have this code :

```
 long yourmilliseconds = Long.parseLong(model_command.getTime());
    Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
```

When I debug and see the date, it gives a date which is 2h hours too early. It only gives this issues on the emulator (It is probably not programmed in the local hours). I would like to fix this issues to be sure that I always get the hours in the TimeZone GTM+02 but I don't know how to specificly say that.

I have tried something like this :

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    long yourmilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTM+02"));
    String test = format.format(resultdate).toString(); /**DATE**/
```

but the lines : `format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTM+02"));`
 seems to be ignored and it still gives the wrong time

Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: The above code is working for me with this change `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+02")` and also you don't need this `toString()`

Comment: It’s one of the confusing traits of the poorly designed and long outdated `TimeZone` class: `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTM+02")` gives you GMT. Hard to believe, so try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GTM+02` is not a valid `ZoneId`, I believe it should be `GMT+02`.

Answer (score 3):

`SimpleDateFormat` is a legecy one use the `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` from java 8

```
OffsetDateTime i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(yourmilliseconds)
        .atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));

String dateTime = i.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));  //2019-07-26 18:01:49
```

However, for far the most purposes better than specifying an offset is specifying a time zone in *region/city* format, for example Europe/Brussels:

```
ZonedDateTime i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(yourmilliseconds)
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels"));
```

On Android API levels under 26 you need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) for this, the modern solution to work.  See this [question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) for a thorough explanation.

Comment: It says that it requires API 26 and I'm only at 21, do you have other option?

Comment: are you on java 8?

Comment: How do I see that? I'm coding on Android Studio (latest version) and I set API to 21

Comment: The above code in the post is working for me with this change `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+02")` and also you don't need this `toString()` @ImNeos